# Table component not updating on first click of search

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

Am trying to add a table component in parent.vue in which there is a search form. When input the right name, I have to click the button twice to show up the table data. I tried to print out the data in parent when click search for the first time, it succeeded. It means that the table was not updated when the variable `parentlistdata` changed for the first time.

The component was integrated in parent.vue, before the component separated from the parent.vue, the table showed up the right data at the first click on search.

Did I make something wrong there?

Thanks.

parent.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="app-container">
    <div >
      <el-input 
        placeholder="input name" 
        v-model="searchData" 
        type="primary" 
        @keyup.enter.native="search"
      >              
      <el-button
        slot="append"    
        @click="search"
      >Search
      </el-button>
      </el-input>
    </div>
    <ListTable :parentlistdata="parentlistdata" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  components: { 
    ListTable: () => import('@/components/ListTable'),
  },
  data() {
    return {
      parentlistdata: null,
      searchData: '',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    search() {
      this.parentlistdata = null
      if (this.searchData.toLowerCase() == "simon") {
        const item = {
          mid: '0001',
          name: 'Simon',
          gender: 'male',
          birthdate:'1988-07-30',
          status: 'normal',
          display_time: '2020-07-22 10:23:12'
        };
        this.parentlistdata = [item]        

      }
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

component: listTable.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="app-container" style="background-color: #fff; margin: 20px;">
    <el-table
      v-loading="listLoading"
      :data="pageListData"
      stripe
      element-loading-text="Loading"
      border
      fit
      highlight-current-row
      :header-cell-style="{background:'#eee',color:'#666'}"
    >
      <el-table-column align="center" width="200" label="ID">
        <template slot-scope="scope">
          {{ scope.row.mid }}
        </template>
      </el-table-column>
      <el-table-column label="name">
        <template slot-scope="scope">
          {{ scope.row.name }}
        </template>
      </el-table-column>
      <el-table-column label="gender" align="center">
        <template slot-scope="scope">
          <span>{{ scope.row.gender }}</span>
        </template>
      </el-table-column>
      <el-table-column label="birthdate" align="center">
        <template slot-scope="scope">
          {{ scope.row.birthdate }}
        </template>
      </el-table-column>
      <el-table-column class-name="status" label="status" align="center">
        <template slot-scope="scope">
          <el-tag :type="scope.row.status | statusFilter">{{ scope.row.status }}</el-tag>
        </template>
      </el-table-column>
      <el-table-column align="center" prop="created_at" label="date">
        <template slot-scope="scope">
          <i class="el-icon-time" />
          <span> {{ scope.row.display_time }}</span>
        </template>
      </el-table-column>
      <el-table-column width="100" align="center"
        label="operation">       
          <template slot-scope="scope">
          <el-button
            @click.native.prevent="viewInfo(scope.row.mid)"
            type="text"
            size="small">
            view
          </el-button>
        </template>      
      </el-table-column>
    </el-table>

    <el-pagination
      @size-change="handleSizeChange" 
      @current-change="handleCurrentChange"
      :current-page="page" 
      :page-sizes="[6, 12, 24]" 
      :page-size="limit"
      background
      layout="total, prev, pager, next, sizes, jumper"
      :total="total"
      style="padding-top: 20px; text-align: right;"
      >
    </el-pagination>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "ListTable",
  props: ["parentlistdata"],
  filters: {
     statusFilter(status) {
         const statusMap = {
           normal: 'success',
           noContact: 'warning',
           lost: 'danger'
         }
         return statusMap[status]
     }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      listData: null,
      pageListData: null,
      limit: 12,
      total: null,
      page: 1,
      listLoading: false,
    }
  },
  watch: {
    parentlistdata(n, o){
      this.listData = n
      this.goNext()
    }   
  },
  methods: {
    goNext() {
        this.pageListData = this.listData.filter((item, index) =>
            index < this.page * this.limit && index >= this.limit * (this.page - 1)
        )
        this.total = this.listData.length
    },
    handleSizeChange(val) {
        this.limit = val
        this.goNext()
    },
    handleCurrentChange(val) {
        this.page = val
        this.goNext()
    },
    viewInfo(mid) {
      this.$router.push({path:'memberInfo',query:{mid}})
    }

  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set parentlistdata to [] instead of null.   Same in the data.

I'm surprised that you don't have any errors, because it tries to filter on null at this moment :
this.parentlistdata = null

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work too. BTW, you're right the filter is absent, I removed some codes in the question so that the question be simpler, but somehow deleted the filter.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue, at the end of the search function add this line of code:

```
this.$forceUpdate();
```